# sql server select only part of string column in result set

Tags: sql-server-2012, varcharmax

I have table T with column A as `Varchar(max)` when I select this field in result pan it only show part of data of this column(only 1457 character) but len(A) return 1730 character.
when I select A the result end  with this string:

```
DSL-combined-Line-Info:
```

but when I select right(A) it give me another string.

```
select
    packet,
    len(packet) as lenght
FROM  [CDR]
where stopTime='2013-05-01 00:00:00.123' and LoginName=2612536328
```

the `packet`column in the result pane give me only 1457 character but len(packet) give me 1730 in the result

Comment: thanks I put the code in the question pan

Comment: Have a look at your [Maximum Characters Retrieved](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190078.aspx)

Comment: maximum character Retrieved is set to 65535 character

Comment: what option I must set?

Comment: i execute in query from linked server this option must set in source server or the server that execute linked server query?